# Can not clone lxc container with lvm backingstore after ubuntu update

Tags: lvm, lxc, clone

Command

```
lxc-clone -s -K -M -H -o debian7 -n debian7-bak
```

Result

```
lxc_container: bdev.c: mount_unknown_fs: 209 failed to determine fs type for '/dev/vg/debian7'
lxc_container: bdev.c: detect_fs: 320 failed mounting /dev/vg/debian7 onto /container/debian7/debian7 to detect fstype
lxc_container: bdev.c: detect_fs: 298 child exited early - fstype not found
lxc_container: bdev.c: bdev_copy: 3090 failed getting pathnames for cloned storage: /dev/vg/debian7
lxc_container: lxccontainer.c: copy_storage: 2489 Error copying storage clone failed
```

Issue after Trusty update to 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you know this, assuming you are the same "questioner" that opened the bug, but for the benefit of future searchers like me:

This is covered at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1414771; the fix has been [committed](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/commit/730e3f9e2ffcc7e34c4236a37215f6be8c8cc7f3), and will be in a future release. In the meantime, as suggested in the bug, the workaround is to create a directory `${LXC_PATH}/${LXC_NAME}/${DEV_NAME}` where

- `${LXC_PATH}` is the directory where container information is stored (`lxc-config lxc.lxcpath`) - normally `/var/lib/lxc`
- `${LXC_NAME}` is the name of the container you are trying to clone
- `${DEV_NAME}` is the last component of the device containing the root filesystem of the container you are trying to clone (`lxc-info --name "${LXC_NAME}" -c lxc.rootfs`)

Comment: You are right I am the same "questioner". Your solution works fine, THX.